i want apply zoom effect in my e-commerce applicationwhich is in nextjs 14
my data is show in frontend from backend side means when admin is add product image then this image is show in the frontend and code is given below where i am use ReactImageMagnify but this code is not generate my expected output when i  write this code it is show output like 
// react
'use client';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useState } from 'react';
import ReactImageMagnify from 'react-image-magnify';

// next
import BlurImage from 'src/components/blurImage';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';
// mui
import { Box, Stack, IconButton, useMediaQuery, Tooltip } from '@mui/material';
import { IoMdHeartEmpty } from 'react-icons/io';
import { IoIosHeart } from 'react-icons/io';
// redux
import { setWishlist } from 'src/lib/redux/slices/wishlist';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
// api
import * as api from 'src/services';
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';
// framer motion
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

// styles override
import RootStyled from './styled';

const variants = {
  enter: (direction) => {
    return {
      x: direction > 0 ? 1000 : -1000,
      opacity: 0
    };
  },
  center: {
    zIndex: 1,
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1
  },
  exit: (direction) => {
    return {
      zIndex: 0,
      x: direction < 0 ? 1000 : -1000,
      opacity: 0
    };
  }
};

/**
 * Experimenting with distilling swipe offset and velocity into a single variable, so the
 * less distance a user has swiped, the more velocity they need to register as a swipe.
 * Should accomodate longer swipes and short flicks without having binary checks on
 * just distance thresholds and velocity > 0.
 */
const swipeConfidenceThreshold = 10000;
const swipePower = (offset, velocity) => {
  return Math.abs(offset) * velocity;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
ProductDetailsCarousel.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onClickWishList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  wishlist: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  isMobile: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  _id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

function ProductDetailsCarousel({ ...props }) {
  const { item, onClickWishList, wishlist, isLoading, isMobile, _id } = props;

  return (
    <div className="slide-wrapper">
      <Stack
        sx={{
          bgcolor: 'background.paper',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: isMobile ? 7 : 12,
          right: isMobile ? 5 : 14,
          borderRadius: '50%',
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          zIndex: 999,
          img: {
            borderRadius: '50%'
          }
        }}
      >
        {wishlist?.filter((v) => v === _id).length > 0 ? (
          <Tooltip title="Remove from cart">
            <IconButton
              disabled={isLoading}
              onClick={onClickWishList}
              aria-label="add to cart"
              color="primary"
              size={isMobile ? 'small' : 'medium'}
            >
              <IoIosHeart />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        ) : (
          <Tooltip title="Add to wishlist">
            <IconButton
              disabled={isLoading}
              onClick={onClickWishList}
              aria-label="add to wishlist"
              size={isMobile ? 'small' : 'medium'}
            >
              <IoMdHeartEmpty />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        )}
      </Stack>
      {item && (
        <ReactImageMagnify
          smallImage={{
            alt: 'Small Image',
            isFluidWidth: true,
            src: item?.src || item?.url,
            onError: (e) => {
              console.error('Error loading small image:', e);
            }
          }}
          largeImage={{
            src: item?.src || item?.url,
            width: 1200,
            height: 1800
          }}
        />
      )}
      <Box className="bg-overlay" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function CarouselAnimation({ ...props }) {
  const { product, data: others } = props;
  console.log(product, 'imageIndex');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const _id = others?._id;

  const images = product?.images;
  const { wishlist } = useSelector(({ wishlist }) => wishlist);
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(({ user }) => user);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { mutate } = useMutation(api.updateWishlist, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      toast.success(data.message);
      setLoading(false);
      dispatch(setWishlist(data.data));
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      setLoading(false);
      const message = JSON.stringify(err?.response?.data?.message);
      toast.error(message);
    }
  });
  const onClickWishList = async (event) => {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      router.push('/auth/login');
    } else {
      event.stopPropagation();
      setLoading(true);
      await mutate(_id);
    }
  };
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)');
  const { themeMode } = useSelector(({ settings }) => settings);
  const [[page, direction], setPage] = useState([0, 0]);
  const imageIndex = Math.abs(page % images?.length);

  const paginate = (newDirection) => {
    setPage([page + newDirection, newDirection]);
  };

  return (
    <RootStyled>
      <AnimatePresence initial={false} custom={direction}>
        <motion.div
          className="motion-dev"
          key={page}
          custom={direction}
          variants={variants}
          initial="enter"
          animate="center"
          exit="exit"
          transition={{
            x: { type: 'spring', stiffness: 300, damping: 30 },
            opacity: { duration: 0.2 }
          }}
          drag="x"
          dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 0 }}
          dragElastic={1}
          onDragEnd={(e, { offset, velocity }) => {
            const swipe = swipePower(offset.x, velocity.x);
            if (swipe < -swipeConfidenceThreshold) {
              paginate(1);
            } else if (swipe > swipeConfidenceThreshold) {
              paginate(-1);
            }
          }}
        >
          <ProductDetailsCarousel
            themeMode={themeMode}
            item={images[imageIndex]}
            index={images[imageIndex]}
            activeStep={imageIndex}
            isActive={imageIndex}
            key={Math.random()}
            isLoading={isLoading}
            wishlist={wishlist}
            onClickWishList={onClickWishList}
            isMobile={isMobile}
            _id={_id}
          />
        </motion.div>
      </AnimatePresence>
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        justifyContent={images.length < 6 ? 'center' : 'left'}
        spacing={1}
        className="controls-wrapper"
      >
        {images.map((item, i) => (
          <Box
            key={Math.random()}
            className={`controls-button ${imageIndex === i ? 'active' : ''}`}
            onClick={() => {
              setPage([i, i]);
            }}
          >
            <BlurImage
              priority
              fill
              objectFit="cover"
              sizes="14vw"
              src={item?.src || item?.url}
              alt="hero-carousel"
              placeholder="blur"
              blurDataURL={item.blurDataURL}
            />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Stack>
    </RootStyled>
  );
}
CarouselAnimation.propTypes = {
  product: PropTypes.object,
  data: PropTypes.object
};


And when i am not import ReactImageMagnify this code is here and output image is here
result before importing ReactImageMagnify 
// react
'use client';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useState } from 'react';
// next
import BlurImage from 'src/components/blurImage';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';
// mui
import { Box, Stack, IconButton, useMediaQuery, Tooltip } from '@mui/material';
import { IoMdHeartEmpty } from 'react-icons/io';
import { IoIosHeart } from 'react-icons/io';
// redux
import { setWishlist } from 'src/lib/redux/slices/wishlist';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
// api
import * as api from 'src/services';
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';
// framer motion
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

// styles override
import RootStyled from './styled';

const variants = {
  enter: (direction) => {
    return {
      x: direction > 0 ? 1000 : -1000,
      opacity: 0
    };
  },
  center: {
    zIndex: 1,
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1
  },
  exit: (direction) => {
    return {
      zIndex: 0,
      x: direction < 0 ? 1000 : -1000,
      opacity: 0
    };
  }
};

/**
 * Experimenting with distilling swipe offset and velocity into a single variable, so the
 * less distance a user has swiped, the more velocity they need to register as a swipe.
 * Should accomodate longer swipes and short flicks without having binary checks on
 * just distance thresholds and velocity > 0.
 */
const swipeConfidenceThreshold = 10000;
const swipePower = (offset, velocity) => {
  return Math.abs(offset) * velocity;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
ProductDetailsCarousel.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onClickWishList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  wishlist: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  isMobile: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  _id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

function ProductDetailsCarousel({ ...props }) {
  const { item, onClickWishList, wishlist, isLoading, isMobile, _id } = props;

  return (
    <div className="slide-wrapper">
      <Stack
        sx={{
          bgcolor: 'background.paper',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: isMobile ? 7 : 12,
          right: isMobile ? 5 : 14,
          borderRadius: '50%',
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          zIndex: 999,
          img: {
            borderRadius: '50%'
          }
        }}
      >
        {wishlist?.filter((v) => v === _id).length > 0 ? (
          <Tooltip title="Remove from cart">
            <IconButton
              disabled={isLoading}
              onClick={onClickWishList}
              aria-label="add to cart"
              color="primary"
              size={isMobile ? 'small' : 'medium'}
            >
              <IoIosHeart />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        ) : (
          <Tooltip title="Add to wishlist">
            <IconButton
              disabled={isLoading}
              onClick={onClickWishList}
              aria-label="add to wishlist"
              size={isMobile ? 'small' : 'medium'}
            >
              <IoMdHeartEmpty />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        )}
      </Stack>
      {item && (
        <BlurImage
          priority
          fill
          objectFit="cover"
          sizes="50%"
          src={item?.url || item?.src}
          alt="hero-carousel"
          placeholder="blur"
          blurDataURL={item.blurDataURL}
        />
      )}
      <Box className="bg-overlay" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function CarouselAnimation({ ...props }) {
  const { product, data: others } = props;
  console.log(product, 'imageIndex');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const _id = others?._id;

  const images = product?.images;
  const { wishlist } = useSelector(({ wishlist }) => wishlist);
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(({ user }) => user);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { mutate } = useMutation(api.updateWishlist, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      toast.success(data.message);
      setLoading(false);
      dispatch(setWishlist(data.data));
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      setLoading(false);
      const message = JSON.stringify(err?.response?.data?.message);
      toast.error(message);
    }
  });
  const onClickWishList = async (event) => {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      router.push('/auth/login');
    } else {
      event.stopPropagation();
      setLoading(true);
      await mutate(_id);
    }
  };
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)');
  const { themeMode } = useSelector(({ settings }) => settings);
  const [[page, direction], setPage] = useState([0, 0]);
  const imageIndex = Math.abs(page % images?.length);

  const paginate = (newDirection) => {
    setPage([page + newDirection, newDirection]);
  };

  return (
    <RootStyled>
      <AnimatePresence initial={false} custom={direction}>
        <motion.div
          className="motion-dev"
          key={page}
          custom={direction}
          variants={variants}
          initial="enter"
          animate="center"
          exit="exit"
          transition={{
            x: { type: 'spring', stiffness: 300, damping: 30 },
            opacity: { duration: 0.2 }
          }}
          drag="x"
          dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 0 }}
          dragElastic={1}
          onDragEnd={(e, { offset, velocity }) => {
            const swipe = swipePower(offset.x, velocity.x);
            if (swipe < -swipeConfidenceThreshold) {
              paginate(1);
            } else if (swipe > swipeConfidenceThreshold) {
              paginate(-1);
            }
          }}
        >
          <ProductDetailsCarousel
            themeMode={themeMode}
            item={images[imageIndex]}
            index={images[imageIndex]}
            activeStep={imageIndex}
            isActive={imageIndex}
            key={Math.random()}
            isLoading={isLoading}
            wishlist={wishlist}
            onClickWishList={onClickWishList}
            isMobile={isMobile}
            _id={_id}
          />
        </motion.div>
      </AnimatePresence>
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        justifyContent={images.length < 6 ? 'center' : 'left'}
        spacing={1}
        className="controls-wrapper"
      >
        {images.map((item, i) => (
          <Box
            key={Math.random()}
            className={`controls-button ${imageIndex === i ? 'active' : ''}`}
            onClick={() => {
              setPage([i, i]);
            }}
          >
            <BlurImage
              priority
              fill
              objectFit="cover"
              sizes="14vw"
              src={item?.src || item?.url}
              alt="hero-carousel"
              placeholder="blur"
              blurDataURL={item.blurDataURL}
            />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Stack>
    </RootStyled>
  );
}
CarouselAnimation.propTypes = {
  product: PropTypes.object,
  data: PropTypes.object
};

i want to only apply zoom effect on the src={item?.src || item?.url} .  not               blurDataURL={item.blurDataURL} and ui is not change after applying zoom effect .
This is BlurImage.jsx
'use client';
// import { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// next
import Image from 'next/image';
// mui
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';
export default function BlurImage({ ...props }) {
  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');
  return <Image sizes={isDesktop ? '14vw' : '50vw'} {...props} src={props.src} alt={props.alt} />;
}
BlurImage.propTypes = {
  src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  alt: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  static: PropTypes.boolean
  // Additional Image props can be added based on your usage
};


